# How do I create a Lua table from an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, database, string, lua

I am getting data from a database with the query:

```
    $queryMessageUsers = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM chatMessages ORDER BY messageId DESC LIMIT $numMessages") or die('Could not query'); 

    if (!$queryMessageUsers) {
            die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }
```

My data is of the format **[id] [Username] [message] [time]**

And then I am putting the data received into an array as follows:

```
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryMessageUsers)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
```

What I am trying to find out is a way in PHP to convert my data into an [LUA TABLE](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TablesTutorial) and output it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php ?

Comment: Because in my code, I want the column names to be the key for the associated data instead of numbered keys. The link helped me understand more :)